# $watchCollection() with Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a nested array of the form :

```
$scope.itinerary = 
    [
        [
          {name:'x'},
          {name:'y'},
          {name:'z'}
        ],
        [
          {name:'a'},
          {name:'b'},
          {name:'c'}
        ]
    ]
```

And I am doing a $watchCollection using the following :

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function () {
            return $scope.itinerary;
        }, 
        function () {
            console.log("Changed")
        }
);
```

But the `console.log()` is only executed if one of the sub array is deleted or a new array is inserted. If I move an element from One array to another, nothing happens. (eg when I move `{name:'a'}` from one array to another, nothing happens). How do I put a watch on the nested Array ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use deep watch 
The $watch() function takes a third, optional argument for "object equality." If you pass-in "true" for this argument, AngularJS will actually perform a deep-object-tree comparison. This means that within each $digest, AngularJS will check to see if the new and old values have the same structure (not just the same physical reference). This allows you to monitor a larger landscape; however, the deep object tree comparison is far more computationally expensive.

```
$scope.$watch('itinerary',function (newVal,oldVal) {
          console.log(newVal)      

 },true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use $watchCollection, you should use $watch with a third argument set to true.

This will works, but it is also a bad idea for performance if the array is large, so use with caution.

Comparison is done using angular.eaquals comparing to a copied object obtained with angular.copy.

More details at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch